# Using Python to Select Titus Classification in Outlook for multiple emails

Tags: python, outlook, office-automation, titus

As the title says I am trying to automate the titus classification selection with Python in Outlook.  I have seen a VBA possible fix and am wondering if anyone has solved this problem with sending multiple emails at once.  I found the code below as a fix, but I believe it worked with an older version and not the current classification version.  The code doesn't click okay and select a classification.

```
#Imports
import win32com.client

# Open outlook and create new email
olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "My Subject"
newMail.Body = "My Body"
newMail.To  = "their.email@wherever.com"
mailUserProperties  = 
newMail.UserProperties.Add("outlook.comClassification", 1)
mailUserProperties.Value = "Internal"
newMail.Display()
newMail.send()
```

Comment: Have you tried to contact titus developers instead?

Comment: You say this doesn't work, but what is wrong with it? What error or unexpected behavior do you see when executing this code?

Comment: @tconbeer Everything up to "MailUserProperties = " works fine.  The rest of the code doesn't select a classification and click on okay.  I have added the .click() event I found in microsofts documentation but nothing happens.  I need to choose one of the three classifications and click okay on the pop up to send the email and am stuck atm.